# How to run crontab in docker container with django?

Tags: python, django, docker, cron

Currently i am run `python3 manage.py crontab add` in docker bash,but cron not run.
[Please check the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQuDQ.png)

cron adding message show but also return `/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/crontab: not found` error.

email credential is already set.

`cvat/apps/engine/cron.py`

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def cron_mail():
    try:
        send_mail(subject='Test mail',message=f'This is a only test mail.',
                  from_email='send@mail.com', recipient_list=['support@mail.com'])
    except Exception:
        pass
```

`cvat/settings/base.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'django_crontab',
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'cvat.apps.engine.cron.cron_mail'),
]
```

aslo add `django-crontab` in requirements.txt file for install pip packages.

Comment: please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra ok sure